# Creating a custom slack bot in python/AWS lambda

Tags: lambda, automation, bots, slack, chatops

I'm trying to create a custom slack bot in python with which I intend to have private conversation (direct messages). Looking at the documentation, looks like slack bot has to join a channel. How can i have a 1:1 conversation with the custom slack bot I create?

Answer (score 0):

you can have 1:1 conversation with custom slack bot. In your application, replace the `#channel_name` with `@user_name`. However, the message will be posted in `♥ slackbot` direct message